# In a Kafka cluster, Does the controller election happens multiple times?

Tags: apache-kafka

In a Kafka cluster, one of the brokers serves as the controller. My question is, does this controller election will happen again and again even the already elected controller is up and running? If yes, how often this happens? Can we control the time?

Comment: Well, main controller can die, so yes, it happens

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the information. My question is more specific , can this re-election happen when the existing controller is up and running like swapping the controllers to make sure that everyone gets a chance ?

Comment: There will never be more than one, and if it does toggle (I'm not sure why it would need to if the controller is healthy), Zookeeper would be responsible for that election, not just the Kafka cluster. I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "gets a chance" since it's not like a load balancing protocol

Comment: Ok. I think i got the answer. My understanding of your explanation is, unless the existing controller dies, it will continue to be the controller for the cluster's lifetime. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I've not personally watched the controller flip over to another node outside of normal maintenance operations, so I could be wrong, but yes one healthy broker should always remain a controller

Comment: @cricket_007 you are correct that unless the controller dies there is no re-election. The Zookeeper only re-elects when the existing controller dies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zookeeper is responsible for health check for all the brokers in cluster by heartbeat mechanism to keep the broker list current. It also responsible for electing controller either in the very beginning or when the current controller crashes.

So there is no need to re-elect controller, while it is healthy (sending heartbeat to Zookeeper)

Answer (score 1):

To perform the controller re-election while all the brokers are up and running: delete the controller node in the zookeeper which will initiate the controller election again without shutting down any brokers.

Zookeeper-shell command :

```
bin/zookeeper-shell localhost:2181 deleteall /kafka/controller [rmr is deprecated]
```